# Returning contents from an Array

Tags: java, arrays

I try to assign an array of numbers from 1 to 10 using the code below. Basically I am stuck on how to return an array. Do I need a `toString` method ?

```
package arrays1;

import java.util.Arrays;


public class Arrays1 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    private int[] numbers;
    private int DEFAULT_SIZE = 10;


    public Arrays1(int size){
       numbers = new int[DEFAULT_SIZE];

     }
    public int[] add(int[] n)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<numbers.length; i++){

        numbers[i]=n[i];}
        return numbers;

    }
    public int[] getValues(){
    return numbers;

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Arrays1 A = new Arrays1(9);

        System.out.println(A.getValues());
    }



}
```

How do I return contents of an array from this code? Do I need to create a new object?

Comment: What part of your code gives you a problem? Is it `getValues()`? Is it `Arrays1 u = ...`? Please explain.

Comment: Hi 

I want to create an object in the main program, then create another method which will show the contents of the array results. Arrays1 u = new Arrays1(10);

Comment: thanks got this but am getting an error after setting the value of size in the main programme:    Arrays1 u = new Arrays1(10);
    u.getValues();

Comment: so i just made some changes to the code but my         System.out.println(A.getValues());
 does not give me the required output of the arrays from 1 to 10 .. ?

Comment: You can use `Arrays.toString(A.getValues())` in your print statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`A.getValues()` is returning a pointer to the integer array `numbers` object, which is probably the output you're seeing. You don't need a new object, just use the one you made, `Arrays1 A`, and iterate over its contents, so something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Arrays1 A = new Arrays1(9);

        for (int i = 0; i < A.getValues().length; i++){
            System.out.println(A.numbers[i]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, a `toString` method would be useful to serialize the contents of the `numbers` array to a String. But in this case, you should call it like this:

```
Arrays1 a = new Arrays1(9);
System.out.println(a); // it is an implicit call to toString()
```

Another acceptable alternative is to let the serialization to the client's responsibility. In this case, the client should rely on the `getValues()` method, and serialize it by itself:

```
Arrays1 a = new Arrays1(9);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a.getValues()));
```

Another lesser detail: Review your constructor: It does not use the parameter `size`, and that can be confusing.